# Set ImageView based on user selection in settings android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am attemping to make an app that would change a Image based on a users selection of a ListPreference in the settings of my application. There are two pictures, a forest,and an Ocean. When Ocean is selected the value sent to the string is 1, and 2 for the forest, but when I run this code it throws an error saying "Source not found." Any siggestions?

```
 public void showUserSettings() {
     String name;
     String pic;
     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     name = sharedPrefs.getString("your_name", "NULL");
     pic = sharedPrefs.getString("pic_what", "for");
     int whatPic = Integer.parseInt(pic);
     TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
     tvName.setText(name);
     if(whatPic==1) {
              ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iView);
             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ocean);
     }else if(whatPic==2); {
         ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iView);
         img.setImageResource(R.drawable.forest);    
     }

 }
```

}

Comment: Post the exact error.

Comment: That is the error. "Source not found" and a button to set where the source is.